# Texstudio: How to change color of internal pdf viewer?

Tags: texstudio

I apply a dark theme to TeXstudio. Is it possible to make the internal pdf viewer dark, too? Is there at least an option to invert colors?

I do not want to use an external reader because I like the integration with the internal one. However the white background of the internal reader breaks my style.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of inverting the colors, one may [change the background color of the viewer](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1299/) independently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can invert the colors. The setting is only accessible via the menu of the windowed viewer:

1. Open Viewer (embedded)
2. Switch to windowed mode using the toolbar.
3. `Menu -> Configure -> Invert Colors`.
4. Switch back to embedded mode using the toolbar.

The setting is persistent across viewer and program restart, so you have to do it onle once.

Comment: Awesome, that option is well hidden. :) Thanks for that!

Comment: Really great! I couldn't believe there could be a possibility of having such an option.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the pure black background through the setting of Tim Hoffmann. Meanwhile I notice that we can apply the trick Tim Hoffmann proposed, "Options -> Internal PDF Viewer -> Paper Color", more flexibly. I just set paper color to light gray "#d1cfcf". Then I invert the colors to get deep gray background, which is the type I prefer.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made this question recently active and I was able to find it. Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 4):

Strict inversion doesn't alter the contrast, so I prefer to change the page background while writing

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
  \pagecolor{gray}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \section{BlindText}
  \blindtext

  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it's just about the background, there's also `Options -> Internal PDF Viewer -> Paper Color`. Of course, this does not affect texts and other elements in the image. So when changing to very dark paper colors, the contrast will become low.

Comment: Changing the paper color is exactly what I want.